# Testing the difference in distribution between two groups

Tags: r, hypothesis-testing, chi-squared-test

within the framework of an exercise, I have 2 factors: a `type of animal` & a `database`

```
M <- as.table(rbind(c(22000, 2300, 42009,106000), c(380,30,7,260)))
dimnames(M) <- list(Databases=c("database1","database2"), Animals=c("Bird","Dog", "Cat","Mouse"))# 

           Animals
Databases     Bird    Dog    Cat  Mouse
  database1  22000   2300  42009 106000
  database2    380     30      7    260
```

And I would simply like to know if compared to the `database1`, the `database2` follows the same distributions of the number of individuals per animal? For example, here we see that in the `database1` there are many more `Mouse` (`106000` or `69.6%`) while in the `database2` there are only `260` or `38.4%.`

Does someone have an idea of what test I could use to test the difference in repartition between the 2 databases please?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

By inspection, it is pretty clear that `Cat` is
under-represented in the second database. Let's see
how that plays out in a chi-squared test of your
$2\times 4$ contingency matrix.

```
db1 =  c(22000,   2300,  42009, 106000)
db2 =  c(  380,     30,      7,    260)
MAT= rbind(db1,db2);  MAT
     [,1] [,2]  [,3]   [,4]
db1 22000 2300 42009 106000
db2   380   30     7    260

chisq.test(MAT)

        Pearson's Chi-squared test

data:  MAT
X-squared = 1238, df = 3, p-value < 2.2e-16
```

The null hypothesis that the proportions are the
same in the two databases is very strongly rejected
with P-value near $0.$

The sum of the squares of the Pearson Residuals
is the chi-squared statistic $1238.$ Residuals
with the largest absolute value point the way to
the cells in which the observed and expected counts
differed most.

```
chisq.test(MAT)$resi
         [,1]       [,2]        [,3]       [,4]
db1 -1.958478 -0.4334418   0.7695618  0.4790736
db2 31.244842  6.9149717 -12.2773080 -7.6429657
```

So it's birds and cats that have the greatest differences
in proportions. *Ad hoc,* we can look at the $2 \times 2$
contingency matrix for just birds and cats.

```
chisq.test(MAT[,c(1,3)], cor=F)

        Pearson's Chi-squared test

data:  MAT[, c(1, 3)]
X-squared = 690.98, df = 1, p-value < 2.2e-16
```

Based on your interests, you could look at other sub-matrices
as well.  Ordinarily, one would be concerned about
false discovery, doing multiple tests on the same data,
but with P-values as small as this, one can do several
*ad hoc* tests without using methods such as Bonferroni's
to adjust significance levels.

**Addendum** per question in Comment. Suppose we had

```
Db1 =  c(22000,   2300,  42009, 106000)
Db2 =  c(  380,     30,      4,    260)
MTR = rbind(Db1,Db2);  MTR
```

The chi-squared test works OK with the smaller cell
you proposed. Maybe you have read about needing
counts to be above $5.$ That's for 'expected counts' computed from row and column totals, based on $H_0.$
The counts in `MTR` are 'observed counts'. In R you can look at expected counts using `$`-notation:

```
chisq.test(MTR, cor=F)$exp
           [,1]        [,2]       [,3]        [,4]
Db1 22292.79999 2320.921536 41849.3032 105845.9753
Db2    87.20001    9.078464   163.6968    414.0247
```

Because of relatively large row and column totals,
cell [2,3] is OK (along with all the others).
If not, `chisq.test` would show a warning
message in output, saying that the P-value may not be accurate. Then you could use parameter `sim=T` in `chisq.test` to simulate a more useful
P-value.

```
chisq.test(MTR, cor=F)

        Pearson's Chi-squared test

data:  MTR
X-squared = 1249.3, df = 3, p-value < 2.2e-16

> chisq.test(MTR, cor=F)$exp
           [,1]        [,2]       [,3]        [,4]
Db1 22292.79999 2320.921536 41849.3032 105845.9753
Db2    87.20001    9.078464   163.6968    414.0247
```

Comment: Wow thank you very much for all the details. I also had another one, what if now istead of 7 for ```database2-Cat`` I had 4. Could I still use this approach?

Comment: I see why you're asking that. See Addendum to my Answer for this proposed change.

Answer (score 5):

A $\chi^2$-test would be the obvious choice, especially since you do not seem to have a problem with small cell counts.